# Sinking my last ball with a back shot where cue ball bounces back to to pot the black ball

Tags: rules, pool

After pocketing the last ball, the cue ball bounces back to pot the 8 ball, leaving my opponent with 4 object balls. In this situation, who is considered to be the winner? Is it the  the opponent or me, because he is remaining with 4 balls not potted.

Answer (score 2):

In standard BCA ruling (Billiards Congress of America), this would be a loss.

If at any time you pocket the 8-ball, before the rest of your 7 object balls (solids/stripes), or during the shot on your last object ball, the game would end.

The cue-ball must come to a stop after your last object ball has dropped before you can take a legal shot at the 8-ball.